# Include JSP page (in folder1) on another JSP page (in folder2)

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I research about how to include a `JSP` page in another `JSP` page and I found `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` by which I can get the `ROOT` access and can locate any folder or directory from `ROOT`.

It is working fine when I am including assets folder like `<script src='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/assets/js/jquery.js'></script>` but not working when I include `JSP` like `<jsp:include page="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/folder2/myPage.jsp"/>`

It's showing error `javax.servlet.ServletException: File [/ROOT/folder2/myPage.jsp] not found`

But when I hit this `/ROOT/folder2/myPage.jsp` on the browser it's working fine.

Comment: <jsp:include page="/folder2/myPage.jsp"/>: you can only include from the same webapp, and that happens at server-side, not in the browser.So specifying the context path would be useless, and redundant.

Comment: I tried this one also but I am accessing myPage.jsp from folder1 but myPage.jsp is in folder2.

Comment: That's why there is /folder2/ at the beginning of the path.

Comment: Yes, http://localhost:8084/ROOT/folder2/myPage.jsp is working fine but not when I include this on another JSP

Comment: Show us the code of your JSP. The one which tries to include mayPage.jsp.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for helping me. My problem is solved by configuring web.xml, I added JSP entry

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>myjsp</servlet-name>
<jsp-file>/folder1/myPage.jsp</jsp-file>
```

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>myjsp</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/myjsp</url-pattern>
```

and simply I use `/myjsp` in `<jsp:include page="/myjsp"/>` and it's working.
Thank you again.

Comment: All this is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: Because just using `<jsp:include page="/folder2/myPage.jsp"/>` is sufficient, as I already explained in the first comment to your question.